# A straight wire connects the foot of building A and the top of building B, making an angle of 30° with the ground.

Tags: geometry, triangles

A straight wire connects the foot of building A and the top of building B, making an angle of 30° with the ground. The same straight wire is just long enough to connect the top of building B and the top of building A. What will be the ratio of the length of this wire to the length of the wire that connects the top of building A and the bottom of building B?

[image: This is the diagram thus formed]

All I want to know is how is AM=A'M? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $M{}{}$?

Comment: Hint: since AB=A’B then ABA’ must be an isosceles triangle

Comment: You need to edit an A to be A'!

Comment: @Mufasa Exactly what I was having a doubt with. If it says that the wire is 'just long' enough to reach the top of two buildings, how can we say that AB=A’B? Is it not possible that 'just long enough' means that the length AB is able to cover the hypotenuse distance between two points A and B, but still be different in length. I mean, what if A'B is of some length, and AB of another different length and yet able to cover the top of two buildings?

Comment: “Just long enough” here implies that it equal to that length.  If it wasn’t then they would have worded it as something like “just short of” to imply it was just too short or “long enough” to imply that it “might” actually be longer.

Comment: @Mufasa Gotcha, thank you so much.